# Error installing thrift on mac yosemite

Tags: qt, osx-yosemite, thrift, autotools

I followed these steps to install thrift on MAC Yosemite :

1. Downloaded and unzipped the package from : http://archive.apache.org/dist/thrift/0.9.0/
2. Followed the steps on this page :
   https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/os_x

But I am facing the following error, after I run ./configure command :

**./configure: line 17810: syntax error near unexpected token `QT,'
./configure: line 17810:`    PKG_CHECK_MODULES(QT, QtCore >= 4.3, QtNetwork >= 4.3, have_qt=yes, have_qt=no)'**

Can somebody help?

Comment: Is that [this one](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1348)? If yes, then maybe you should upgrade to a more recent version, if installing `pck-config` doesn't do the trick.

Comment: I have pkg-config installed. I checked it by running pkg-config --version and got 0.28 as the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It seems the pkg-config installed on my machine was not brew installed pkg-config. So, uninstalled and installed pkg-config using brew. This resolved the above issue. After that, I also found that automake installed on my machine was 1.15 and I need automake 1.12 to install thrift 0.9.0.

Comment: brew install automake@1.12

Comment: try 1.15 + don't forget brew link automake